# Java Native Interface loading dll file

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am trying to load a DLL file in java program. I do not get an error. However, the DLL library is not loaded. Here is the code snippet:

```
final class TJLoader {
  static void load() {
    //System.loadLibrary("@TURBOJPEG_DLL_NAME@");
      String path = "C:/Eclipse2/mozpeg-master/bin";
      try {
            System.out.println("before loading");
            //System.loadLibrary("cygjpeg-62");
            System.load("C:/image_test/mozjpeg-master/.libs/cygjpeg-62.dll");

            System.out.println("2");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("exception="+e);
    }catch(Error e){
        System.out.println("error="+e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

On the console I will get "before loading". However, there is nothing printed after that and the program ends abruptly. Please note the DLL is a 62 bit library and I am using 62 bit JVM

Comment: (64-bit, I think "62" in dll name would be software version) -- Can you try starting the program with `java -XX:ErrorFile=/path/to/file.log -jar myapp.jar` (adapt path and jar name and classmate if necessary), get it to crash again, and see if you get a crash file at specified location? (You might already have one in current directory, actually)

Comment: Still it is not producing any ErrorFile. Anything, which i can do in library to get the root cause of crash

Comment: I just noticed the library name gives a hint that this DLL might depend on cygwin.dll. It [seems Cygwin & JNI are not good friends](http://elliotth.blogspot.com/2005/08/porting-jni-code-to-win32-with-cygwin.html). See in particular "problem two", which might explain the behavior you get. Do you think there are non-Cygwin builds of that library you're trying to use?

Comment: Try to catch `Throwable`

Comment: Failures in DLL loading will produce native and not Java errors. You can't catch these in Java. They just make the program exit. That's why you don't see any message after the failed load. Make sure you got all dependencies. (And as Hugues said, it might be better to avoid Cygwin if possible)

Comment: thanks...this was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Failure in DLL Loading actually produce java errors. Native errors are produced when you try to invoke a native method. I got java error like "Library not found" when my program failed to load the DLL. You should make sure that your DLL is a 64-bit build and also,try to avoid Cygwin. I used Visual studio to build the DLL and it works fine.Also keep in mind to take the release version instead of the debug version.